# How to renice a make with multiple jobs?

Tags: make

I'm running very large kernel compile, and I would like to `renice` the whole process to at least `-1`, so it gets a little bit more CPU time. Currently, I'm not running anything else on the machine.

The compile is already running, and I don't want to stop it. Is there anyway to `renice` all the jobs that are `spawned`? I had tried:

```
renice -n -10 -p [the make process]
```

But everything spawned is still a `priority 0`.

Comment: If the host isn't doing anything other than compiling and keeping its own house in order, you're not going to see much benefit with a `renice` to my understanding.  That would only come into play if there is contention for CPU resources, and if the compiler is the only thing really taxing the CPU, there'd not by anything for it to change.

Comment: Based on my reading, it will increase the time quantum. If it's not contending with anything, it will get the CPU again, but the more times that happens, the more time is spent in overhead

Answer (score 0):

The [`pstree`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/psmisc/pstree.1.en.html) tool can already display a tree of processes. It doesn't have a "raw" output mode so some output's parsing is required.

It's racy (the time it's computed, some processes already appeared or disappeared) and could be prone to parsing errors (eg if a subprocess changes its name and mimics pstree's output with numbers and parentheses). As long as total reliability isn't required, this should do the job:

```
MAKE_PID=[the make process]
renice -n -10 -p $(pstree -p $MAKE_PID | grep -o '([1-9][0-9]*)'|tr -d '()')
```

In short: display the tree including the pid for each process, keep only the pid values: numbers between parentheses, remove the parentheses, feed the result to renice.